# Limit value of logarithm term using sum-representation

Tags: limits, logarithms

I want to correctly prove the following statement:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x \cdot \ln\left(\frac{x + a}{x - a}\right)} = \frac{1}{2a} \ , \ a \in \mathbb{R}^{\ast+} 
\end{equation}

This should atleast be true for $a \in \mathbb{R}^{\ast+}$, but I have no idea how to correctly prove it, as the logarithm rules don't seem to be of any help here. When using the sum-statement of the logarithm for the denominator we should get:

\begin{equation}
x \cdot \left(\frac{2a}{(x-a)} - \frac{2a^2}{(x-a)^2} + \frac{8a^3}{3(x-a)^3} - \frac{4a^4}{(x-a)^4} + HOT\right)
\end{equation}

While the first term resembles the statement wo are looking for, can we actually just say that the rest of the terms tends to zero "fast" enough? And what would happen if $a$ tends to $\infty$ as well?

**Edit:** changed the statement so that it is mathematically correct. The previous statement was:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{x + a}{x - a}\right)} = \frac{x}{2a} \ , \ a \in \mathbb{R}^{\ast+} 
\end{equation}

The funtion approaches $\infty$ in a linear way with the factor $\frac{1}{2a}$.

Comment: How can you have $x$ in the answer when you have $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to make a change of variable $t=\frac{x}{a}$ and then divide the expression by $t$. Then you would have something that approaches $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DS It approaches infinty in a linear way just like a function y = x would do. While the actual limit therefore naturally is infinty, I wanted to make clear "how fast" it does so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute the limit: $\lim_{x\to \infty}x\ \log\left(\frac{x+c}{x-c}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025095/compute-the-limit-lim-x-to-inftyx-log-left-fracxcx-c-right) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cln%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%20%2B%20a%7D%7Bx%20-%20a%7D%5Cright)%24)

Comment: @MartinR Yes is does! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln\left(\frac{x+a}{x-a} \right)}
= \frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{\frac{x}{a}-1} \right)}
$$
With the variable change $t=\frac{x}{a}$, we have
$$
g(t) = \frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{t-1} \right)}
$$
Now we're interested in the value of $\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t)/t$. Using Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+x)$, we get
$$
\ln(1+s) = s - \frac{s^2}{2} + \frac{s^3}{3} + \ldots 
$$
we get $\lim_{s \to 0} \ln(1+s) \approx s$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{t} \right) \approx \frac{2}{t}
$$
Combining the previous points, we get
$$
\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{t-1} \right)} \to \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{t} \right)}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{g(t)}{t} \approx \frac{1}{t\left(\frac{2}{t} \right)} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Sorry for the slightly hand-wavy points, but I think this approach should yield the result.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the reciprocal
$$\log \left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right)$$ Using long division
$$\frac{x+a}{x-a}=1+\frac{2 a}{x}+\frac{2 a^2}{x^2}+\frac{2
   a^3}{x^3}+\frac{2
   a^4}{x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
By Taylor
$$\log \left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right)=\frac{2 a}{x}+\frac{2 a^3}{3
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
Long division
$$\frac 1 {\log \left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right) }=\frac{x}{2 a}-\frac{a}{6
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$